# How can you forget a wi-fi connection you've used

Tags: networking

I have used a wi-fi connection that requires a password. But it is flaky and I now have my own wi-fi to use. But occasionally my computer still uses the first wi-fi. If I could make my ubuntu forget that password, it wouldn't use try the flaky connection anymore. (I am using Ubuntu 18.04.05 LTS)

Comment: System settings > Wi-Fi. Click the cogwheel. Can you see a huge red button?

Comment: If you go to `Network -> Settings` can you not see the connection there where you can turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a GUI alternative to remove the connection. I presume you are using the GNOME environment.

Go to: the System status area;
Click the Wifi connection;
Go to WIFI settings from the drop-down;
Click the icon that resembles three dots arranged vertically;
Select known Wi-Fi networks;
Select the Wi-Fi connection and Click 'Forget' to remove the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all known networks by running the following command:

```
sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
```

Alternatively, you can use the `rm` command to delete the individual network by name.

First, run the following command to list all saved networks:

```
ls /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
```

Then, delete the network by name. For example, if the network is named "coffee-shop", you would use the following command:

```
sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/coffee-shop
```

Finally, restart NetworkManager to apply the changes:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```